# Prevent my node.js app to be killed by the OS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I m creating a web tv on a Raspberry Pi

Since the RPi will not always be connected to the net, I need to download the file it will have to play before playing them.

I can download the file, but when I m starting too much download, either by starting them all-at-once or one after another (wich take a lot more time), my app end up killed by the linux system.

Is there any way, in javascript, in node.js, in bash or by editing my algo, to prevent the app from being killed?

Comment: Look inside system log files (e.g. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`, or the output of `dmesg` command) for messages relative to your application (or to the `node.js` processes)

Comment: Thanks, it seems I run out of memory, I ll modify to download one after another, and see if I can make it work this way. I ll accept your comment as answer if you post it as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>as I commented ...</sup>

Look inside system log files (e.g. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`, or the output of `dmesg` command) for messages relative to your application (or to the `node.js` processes). You may have gotten out of resources....

Comment: On my CentOS it was /var/log/messages: Apr 26 20:22:08 mother kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 26146 (node) score 201 or sacrifice child
Apr 26 20:22:08 mother kernel: Killed process 26146, UID 0, (node) total-vm:1116472kB, anon-rss:115504kB, file-rss:36kB