# Linux kill my process for out of memory, how to see how much I use?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Following my previous question ([Prevent my node.js app to be killed by the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589674/prevent-my-node-js-app-to-be-killed-by-the-os)) I have remade my gestion of how I download the files.

To make it short, I need to download some video files (test files are 3 video, mp4, ~3min), I was downloading them all at once, the process was getting killed and dmesg was saying (after 2 download completed):

```
Out of memory: kill process (node) score 824 or sacrifice child
Killed process (node)...
```

So I retried by downloading the video one after another, but at the second download, I get the exact same message, and my program get killed.

Is there some way to see which part of my code go wrong, or to prevent linux from killing my process?

BTW, isn t three simultaneous download eat up more memory than one? So why do I get kill faster on the one-after-another?

The app is running on a raspberry pi, no GUI, raspbian, and I believe to be the only app running (other than system process)

EDIT:
Some details about the function and how I think it would work now:
The app is started in node, not in any browser.
Since it download the video one after another, I was thinking it would eat less memory, but it seems to be wrong since I download more data while firing all at once, and the reason is stop seems to be the same.

Here the download function, in case it could help:

file_url is of type http://adress.com/rpi/test.mp4

```
function download (file_url, callback){
    var option={host:url.parse(file_url).host, port:80, path:url.parse(file_url).pathname};
    var file_name=url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
    var file=fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR+file_name);
    //Seems to crash while here:
    http.get(options, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(data){
            file.write(data);
        }).on('end'), function(){
            file.end();
            callback(DOWNLOAD_DIR+file_name);
        });
    });
};
```

I m sure this function do work since I did download some files with it successfully.

Here how I made the download follow:
(
This function may not work completely right, I do not ask for debug, I never get to end it.)

```
function download_all (list, callback){
    var i=0;
    function follow(){
        i=i+1;
        if (i<list.length){
            download(DOWNLOAD_ADD+list[i], follow);
        }
    }
    download(DOWNLOAD_ADD+list[0], follow);
}
```

EDIT2:

Since I still didn t found a way to core dump or the other solution proposed by Roman, I used process.memoryUsage to print it while downloading.

heapTotal is slowly increasing all along the process, between 20 000 000 and 25 000 000, with some drop. heapUsed is increasing quickly, and drop regulary to ~2 000 000 when going higher than 6 000 000, with some spike at ~12 000 000.

When the process got killed, the last print was:
rss: 428 707 840, heapTotal: 23 842 176, heapUsed: 5 854 164

I m note sure of how to read it yet, but it seems to me that the process was far from eating all the memory...

I m still reading docs about core dumping and /proc/

EDIT3:

My tech director suggested that the download was maybe cached then writed the entire file on the disk, wich could explain the memory usage. It don t really stick with the all-at-once case since I could end the download of 2 video and get killed while it ended the third, but I m now searching about that too

EDIT4:

Nevermind last edit, I was already writing by chunk, wich give us the question about why the memory get ate up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to identify what system process is killed by OS.
Then I'd enable `.core` dumping and analyse it. Please check for `ulimit -c` command and 
appropriate configuration to get this. Of course you need to enable debug symbols for your program to get most of it.

In case you cannot dump (have no sufficient space or any other limitation), consider remote debug with debug version of process on client side. I think you should be able to use something like 'remote GDB debugging' for this.

Most probably your process fails on some memory allocation and this has great chance to explain where you 'eat' memory, who is guilty and probably what to do with this.

Hope this will help.

Comment: The process killed is node.js, which I start while launching my app. ulimit -c give me 0, and since my app don t start in any browser nor is compilled, I don t find any way to see debugging symbol. Since I don t do any memory allocation myself, I assume http.get do some, but I still don t understand why the process is killed faster when it s supposed to eat less memory. I m searching how to dump the core, since I never done that, nor have a lot of experience on *nix systems. I ll give more details when I can get some.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `/proc/` file system (notably `/proc/self/statm` or `/proc/$PID/statm` etc...), see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to get status of memory.

There are other interesting pseudo-files in `/proc/` notably `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/$PID/maps` etc...